# Why does Flutter Image Picker take 2-3 seconds to capture an image from the camera on Android?

Tags: android, flutter, camera, imagepicker, flutter-image-picker

## Flutter Image picker is taking a while to capture image from camera on android

When I try to pick image using image_picker package , camera open file , but when I click capture button it takes about 2 or 3 seconds to capture image , any solutions ?
code:

> ```
> void pickImageFromCam() async {
> try {
> await ImagePicker()
>           .pickImage(
> source: kIsWeb ? ImageSource.gallery : ImageSource.camera,
> requestFullMetadata: true,
> imageQuality: 90,
> maxHeight: 500,
> maxWidth: 500)
>           .then((value) {
> if (value != null) {
> if (imagesExtensions.contains(getExtension(value.name))) {
> pickedFiles.add(CustomPickedFile(
> file: File(value.path),
> path: value.path,
> fileExtension: getExtension(value.name),
> fileName: value.name));
>
> Helper.showSnackBar(context,
> message: AppLocal.of(context).image_was_taken);
> else {
> _showDialog(
> title: AppLocal.of(context).take_photo,
> content: AppLocal.of(context)
>                     .extension_should_be(imagesExtensions.join(' , ')));
>           }
> else {
> _showDialog(
> title: AppLocal.of(context).take_photo,
> content: AppLocal.of(context).no_image_was_taken);
>         }
>       });
> on IOException catch (error) {
> log(error.toString());
>     }
>   }
> ```

[image]

Comment: any suggestions for solutions